# How to change all children elements inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change all elements inside the div with the class ms-rtestate-field
cause they are created dinamically. This is what I accomplished so far, hope you can give me any pointers. Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ms-rtestate-field').each(function() {
    $(this).find("*").css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="" class="ms-rtestate-field">
  <div class="ExternalClass1">
    <div class="ExternalClass2">

      <div class="External3">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <div style="font-size:12pt">text</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't added jQuery in your snippet. I did this for you and adapted your function to affect all children. If your children change after you've called this, you will have to call it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following js code:

```
$(".ms-rtestate-field").each(function() {
    $(this).find("*").css("border", "1px solid blue");//perform whatever you want.
});
```

In case you want to apply this js after dynamic content has loaded then make a function of same code and make a call to that function.

```
function dynamicContent()
{
   $('.ms-rtestate-field').each(function() {
      $(this).find("*").css("border", "1px solid red");
   });  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution you seem to need is not jQuery or Javascript-based, it's actually CSS.

```
.blue-children * {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Now set this CSS class dynamically on all `.ms-rtestate-field` where you need blue-backgrounded items.

Using CSS here allows you to even change children dynamically (e.g. add or append some) and they will be affected, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all the divs which are inside the div.ms-rtestate-field

`$('.ms-rtestate-field > div').css('background-color','blue');`

Comment: @kazzius : when and how do you think you are gonna use this ??

Comment: This will still fail if it is executed *before* the dynamic content is added. That's why the most viable solution is using a CSS class and applying that dynamically.

Comment: @connexo what if it will be called when any input fires and inside some condition, you never know ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ms-rtestate-field').each(function() {
        $(this).find("div").css('background-color','blue');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sometimes there are some other elements with their own styles what I used this: $(this).find("*").css({'background-color':'yellow',
               'font-size' : '20px'
                       
        
             });